# How do I equally balance tmux(1) split panes?

Tags: tmux

I'm looking for a behavior that is similar to how vim(1) handles its split windows with `^w =`. I know tmux(1) has predefined layouts with `^b Meta[1-5]`, but this likely does not have the layout that I am currently using.

When splitting a window, it halves the current window for both panes. Split again, and it halves that pane into two new. Combine vertical and horizontal splits, and they continue to halve each other, each new pane getting smaller and smaller.

How can I keep the new layout I've just created, but have all vertical and horizontal splits equally balanced, like vim(1) does with `^w =`?

Comment: The description for the "tiled" layout says "Panes are spread out as evenly as possible over the window in both rows and columns." Could you explain how what you want is different from this please?

Comment: Sure. This describes it very well: https://gist.github.com/1942422

Answer (score 474, accepted):

**Vertically**

`select-layout even-vertical`
  Usually assigned to: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>

**Horizontally**

`select-layout even-horizontal`
  Usually assigned to: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

Comment: For other people who are wondering: `C-b M-2` means Control-b, and `M-2` means alt+2.

Comment: M-2 means ESC+2 for me on Debian using Gnome Terminal. Probably depends on setup.

Comment: `C-...` and `M-...` are emacs-ims  M- means "meta" which is [Alt] in combination with or [Esc] followed by the referenced key  both options look the same over the wire, but there is the possibility that your GUI may be trapping the [Alt] sequence

Comment: Just to put this here in case it helps someone else, because I am constantly confused, "vertical" and "horizontal" are the direction of the *spacing*--that is, choosing even-vertical will create a layout where the three panes are stacked vertically, equal in height, where even-horizontal will create a layout where the three panes are side-by-side, equal in width

Comment: How to do M-2 on macOS with a keyboard where "2" requires pressing shift (like the French keyboard)? I didn't succeed, with various combinations of alt, control, command, escape and shift + 2…

Comment: Kind of silly but the way I remember which Alt+? key to use is "1" looks like a horizontal pane and "2" looks like 2 panes on top of each other.

Comment: Any way to use Alt+1 in wsl.exe?

Comment: 350th from me! cheers!

Comment: `alt+n` switches to the n'th terminal tab.

Comment: on macOS, there is an Edit menu item "Use Option as Meta" in the Terminal app. Enable that, and you can hold the Option key to type the Meta keys.

Answer (score 164):

You can use <kbd>ctrl-b</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> to cycle through layouts with even spacing, but that won't necessarily preserve the layout you had.

Comment: The idea behind the trick (if you want to map it to something else or adapt it): `bind-key -r Space next-layout`. Then `C-b` `Space` `Space` `Space`...

Comment: Is there a way to know which layout I've selected, and how to quickly jump to it again?

Comment: this is a nice one, let you explore various combinations

Comment: very useful and easy to remember!

Answer (score 44):

From the command line you can use

```
tmux select-layout tiled
```

to make your splits all roughly equal size. You can bind that to a key command as well.

Comment: Usually assigned to: `C-b M-5`

Comment: @minipif That is the answer

Answer (score 8):

I don't know any single key shortcut, but maybe this helps you:

You can try to write some script to do the layout, and bind a key to the script. You can do this by using `tmux`command `pipe-pane [-o] [-t target-pane] [shell-command]` to write the current layout to the script. Next you need to read a layout prepared by the script using `tmux`command `select-layout` .

Answer (score 5):

I was having a hard time finding the magic incantation to split into 4 equal quadrants, so here it is:

```
# Split session into FOUR EQUAL quadrants
tmux selectp -t 0    # select the first (0) pane
tmux splitw -h -p 50 # split it into two halves
tmux selectp -t 0    # select the first (0) pane
tmux splitw -v -p 50 # split it into two halves

tmux selectp -t 2    # select the new, second (2) pane
tmux splitw -v -p 50 # split it into two halves
tmux selectp -t 0    # go back to the first pane
```

Answer (score 5):

tmux provides with some pre defined layouts,
do `tmux select-layout` and you will have some options:

`even-horizontal  even-vertical    main-horizontal  main-vertical    tiled`

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what the different layouts do, and how they address the original question (in ways that haven’t already been covered).

Answer (score 3):

`ctrl b` and then `:resize-pane -M` and then just use your mouse! (requires `mouse-mode` to be enabled)

Comment: mice do not belong in terminals