# How do I split a tmux window into thirds?

Tags: tmux

I like to use a tall terminal window on the right side of my monitor and I wonder if there's a nice way to divide it into even vertical thirds.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32986/how-do-i-equally-balance-tmux1-split-panes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I equally balance tmux(1) split panes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32986/how-do-i-equally-balance-tmux1-split-panes)

Answer (score 4):

select-layout even-vertical
Usually assigned to: `C-b` `M-2`

`C-b` means Control-b, and `M-2` means alt+2.

Comment: Know how to get that to work from a terminal under Mac OS?  option+2 sends ™ instead of alt+2

Comment: @cjm: Preferences -> Profiles -> Keyboard and select "Use Option as Meta key".